# Bounded cube dense in $R^3$

Tags: integration, functional-analysis, lebesgue-integral

I have a sequences of function $(u_n)_{n\in \mathbb{Z}}: \mathbb{R}^3\times [0,\infty)\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^3$ that satisfies
\begin{equation}\lim_{n\to \infty}\int_{B(0,R)} u_n(x,t)dx<\infty\end{equation} where $B(0,R)$ is a bounded cube with rational lenght. And let $a:\mathbb{R}^3\times [0,\infty)\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^3$ be a continuous functions in $L^2(\mathbb{R}^3)$ then I want to show that 
\begin{equation}
\lim_{n\to \infty }\int_{\mathbb{R}^3}u_n(x,t)a(x,t)dx <\infty
\end{equation}

How can I do? I want to use a density argument but I don't know whether the cube is dense in $\mathbb{R}^3$. Can someone help me?

Comment: Generally the product of $L^1$ function with an $L^2$ function is not in $L^1$ so this looks doubtful

Comment: It is actually in the Paper of J.Leray on Fluiddynamics and it is just said that we can show this by means of a "density argument" ... But I don't understand what he means

Comment: What exactly is the product of $\mathbb R^3$ valued functions? Also what is your title all about, makes no sense to me.

Answer (score 0):

Let's note $A_n=\{  x\in \mathbb{R} ^3 | a(x)>u_{n}(x) \}$ so 
$$
\lim_{n\to \infty }\int_{\mathbb{R}^3}u_n(x,t)a(x,t)dx= \lim_{n\to \infty }\int_{A_{n}}u_n(x,t)a(x,t)dx +\lim_{n\to \infty }\int_{A_{n}^c}u_n(x,t)a(x,t)dx \leq
\lim_{n\to \infty }\int_{A_{n}}a^2(x,t)dx +\lim_{n\to \infty }\int_{A_{n}^c}u_{n}^2(x,t)dx \leq
\lim_{n\to \infty }\int_{ \mathbb{R}^3 }a^2(x,t)dx +\lim_{n\to \infty }\int_{ \mathbb{R}^3 }u_{n}^2(x,t)dx
\leq \lim_{n\to \infty }\int_{ \mathbb{R}^3 }a^2(x,t)dx +\lim_{n\to \infty } \Big( \int_{ \mathbb{R}^3 }u_{n}(x,t) \Big) ^2
= \lim_{n\to \infty }\int_{ \mathbb{R}^3 }a^2(x,t)dx +\Bigg( \lim_{n\to \infty }\int_{ \mathbb{R}^3 }u_{n}(x,t) \Bigg) ^2
$$

The second number is finite because it is given in the question and the second is finite becaue $a \in L^2(\mathbb{R}^3)$

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't understand. Where do you use the fact that
\begin{equation}
\lim_{n\to \infty}\int_{B(0,R)}u_n(x,t)dx<\infty
\end{equation}

Comment: No, we don't know about $\int u_n^2$